# LESS call a mixin dynamically

Tags: css, less, mixins

How do you call a mixin dynamically?

A use case might be to generate a style guide:

```
// The mixin which should be called
.typography-xs(){
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

// The mixin which tries to call typography-xs
.typography-demo(@typographyName, @mixinName) {
  @{typographyName} {
    &:before{content: '@{typographyName}';}
    // Calling the mixin dynamically
    @mixinName();
  }
}

// Example call of .typograhpy-demo
.typography-demo(xs, typography-xs);
```

Is such a dynamic call possible at all with less css?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot at present dynamically call as you desire. You can, however, set it up slightly differently using [pattern matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching), like so:

```
// The mixin which should be called
.typography(xs){
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

// The mixin which tries to call typography-xs
.typography-demo(@typographyName) {
  @{typographyName} {
    &:before{content: '@{typographyName}';}
    // Calling the mixin dynamically
    .typography(@typographyName);
  }
}

// Example call of .typograhpy-demo
.typography-demo(xs);
```

Using pattern matching, you can then create other patterns, such as:

```
.typography(xl){
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 44px;
}

.typography(times){
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

Now you can call pattern `xl` or `times` and have it generate the code. Essentially, take whatever you were going to use after the hyphen (like your `-xs`) to distinguish your various typography groups, and remove the hyphen and use that name as your pattern to match the mixins to.

Additionally, I would add a means of putting a selector before the `@{typographyName}` like so:

```
.typography-demo(@typographyName, @selector: ~".") {
  @{selector}@{typographyName} {
    &:before{content: '@{typographyName}';}
    // Calling the mixin dynamically
    .typography(@typographyName);
  }
}
```

This way it generates a class by default, but could be made into an id or any selector string up to the `@{typographyName}`.