# Can I add a variable to a mixin function name in Less?

Tags: css, less

Is this possible to do in some way I don't know? I'm trying to add a variable in the mixin function name.

```
@mybar: Test;

.mymixin() {
  padding: 10px;
}

.mymixin@{mybar}() {
  padding: 10px;
}

.test {
  .mymixinTest();
}
```

Comment: Short answer: **no** you can't. This may give you some inspiration though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798871/less-call-a-mixin-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you do:

```
.myMixin(@myvar) {
      .myMixin@{myvar} {
          //your css
       }
}
```

Comment: You're still generating css. I just want a mixin function with a variable name.

Comment: I guess that wouldn't be possible, I do think similar behaviour can be simulated by above code/modifications to above code, but that's the best that can be done as far as I know. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I don't think LESS is capable of doing what I want do to.